# Solr filter via date range on multivalue field

Tags: solr

I have a document set up at the moment that lists car parts. I currently have everything setup to filter via make, model and type. But i would like to add a date range field.

Sample data:

Product Title
Make
Model 1 - date range
Model 2 - date Range
Model 3 - date range

As you can see there can be multiple models that each have a specific date range the part fits on the vehicle. How could i go about doing this? I cant even think how to index it never mind filter search it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you have one entity(product,title,make,{model1-dateRange1,model2-dateRange2, model3-dateRange3}). And each entity is having a child entity with 2 fields(model, dateRange). Its one to many relation

One way is - use multi value field type. So each document will have multi values. But in your case its not just array of strings(model or date), but array of objects(model and data). So you can use model_date combined and store them as multi values. Format is like [prod1,title1,make1, {model1_date1,model2_date2,model3_date3}]. The tricky part of you have date rather than a string. So while searching based on date(second part of your value), you need to see how this affects. This approach is a denormalized(flat) approach

Another way is using [nested documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments). This is how the current object relations work. More like Parent and child. Parent doc have (product, title,make) and child have(model,date). The relation is maintained by solr. However you should have a field which can differentiate if the docuemnt is child or parent. The good thing in this is, you can search for parent with child attributes and vice versa. Its your choice.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying out nested documents which I can search on but can't seem to be able to facet the child documents.

Comment: can you add moredetail when u say, "cant facet on child" - like how you confirmed it. Because child docs are like any other docs I suppose. Not sure if there are any restrictions on it

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself very well. So I have a query which looks for products where a child doc has a vehicle model and year. I find the the product I need but all the facets come back as empty. Eg product listed for a ford focus , I would search for all docs with doc_type product and then search for ford focus on the  child docs.

Comment: example query is:
{!parent which='type:product'} +productApplicationModel__name:TEST3

with facets on  and facet on field productApplicationModel__name

Comment: When you use !parent in your query, it is used to retrive the parent records which satisfy particular child field value. And you are trying to facet based on child field value, which I think not possible because, you dont have child documents returned. As mentioned in above documentation in main link, you get either parent or child for parent or child match respectivley

Comment: So this sounds like I would need to query twice to get all my facets then?

Comment: So your requirements summing to 1) query match on parent and child fields, 2) get both parent and child for above match, 3) facet on child field. Am I correct? If yes, then i fear, you need 2 queries. Once to fetch all the parent id's and then all children who have the fetched parentId. So both block join query usages.

Comment: I am having issues with php Solr adding nested docs for some reason, without doing a lot of alteration to my current system. so I am attempting to do it with a special date field that will hold a model_year like you said in your first point. Instead of doing a date range I will add each year with vehicle model eg: title:product one make:ford model:fiesta model:focus year:fiesta_2014,fiesta_2015,focus_2015. Then if I need to display years for fiesta I can search for fiesta* and then remove the model of the vehicle when showing the facets! I will attempt this tomorrow! Hope it works!

Comment: Looks good, because you are just having year, and not a complete date. My initial fear is that, with above approach i was assuming you to have complete date, which will make you querying based on date functions difficult. With just year, I hope it should be fine. Post your results, and as usual dont forget to vote/accept the answer if your are fine with solution. Happy coding

Comment: Yeah I was going have a date range but when filtering it's only important that I filter it by year. So when I add a date range to the database I will add each year in the range to the Solr index!. Will post my results and vote if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramzy's the solution used was to use a multivalued field that has the vehicle model and year combined together. As i only required to filter the Year and not the full date i split a date range up (in PHP) into multiple values. Example:

**MYSQL:** 
Brand:Ford Model:Model1 DateFrom:Jan-2011 DateTo:Feb-2013
Brand:Ford Model:Model2 DateFrom:Jan-2011 DateTo:Feb-2011

**Solr:**
Model1_2011,
Model1_2012,
Model1_2013,
Model2_2011,

Then when filtering via year on model2 i would search for:  Model2* which would find all the relevant products/facets, in PHP i would only show those facets which includes Model2. When searching for products of Model2 in 2011 i would search for Model2_2011. More attributes could been added like trim, then the search would change to Model2*2011, which could return: Model2_Trim1_2011.